# What is wrong with my C# code inside .aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to execute my code via .aspx file. But it shows me this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine. 
>        Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag
>   within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory
>   of the current web application. This  tag should then
>   have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I don't have possibility to look into server errors right now or change it settings.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>

<%@ import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Linq"%>


<script runat="server">
public void ReadPublishTxt()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(
            "...\\properties.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Divide all '_'
                string[] lineParts = line.Split('_');

                // Main parameters
                string url = "";
                string title = "";
                string initCode = "";
                string og_desc = "";
                string desc = "";
                string og_img = "";

                // If length == 4, and last index type = string, it means category
                // If length == 4, and last index type = int, it means series
                // If length == 5, it means section

                // Category
                if((lineParts.Length == 4) && (lineParts[3].All(char.IsDigit) == false))
                {
                    url = "...properties/" + lineParts[0] + ".html";
                    title = lineParts[1] + " | ";
                    initCode = "let startPageLink = \"PublishPageContent\"; var categoryNameStart = '" + lineParts[3] + "'; var seriesIds = '';  var infoId = '';";
                    og_desc = " | " + lineParts[2];
                    desc = " " + lineParts[2];
                }
                // Series
                else if ((lineParts.Length == 4) && (lineParts[3].All(char.IsDigit) == true))
                {
                    url = "...properties/" + lineParts[0] + ".html";
                    title = lineParts[1] + "";
                    initCode = "let startPageLink = \"PublishPageContent\"; var categoryNameStart = ''; var seriesIds = '" + lineParts[3] + "';  var infoId = '';";
                    og_desc = " | " + lineParts[2];
                    desc = " " + lineParts[2];
                    og_img = "...properties/images/meta_images/" + lineParts[3] + ".png";
                }
                // Section
                else if (lineParts.Length == 5)
                {
                    url = "...properties/" + lineParts[0] + ".html";
                    title = lineParts[1] + "";
                    initCode = "let startPageLink = \"PublishPageContent\"; var categoryNameStart = ''; var seriesIds = '" + lineParts[4] + "';  var infoId = '" + lineParts[3] + "';";
                    og_desc = "| " + lineParts[2];
                    desc = "| " + lineParts[2];
                    og_img = "...properties/images/meta_images/" + lineParts[3] + ".png";
                }

                // Edit html file with correct data
                string Html = CorrectHtml(url, title, initCode, og_desc, desc, og_img);

                // Create html file
                File.WriteAllText("...properties\\" + lineParts[0] + ".html", Html);
            }
        }
    }

private  string CorrectHtml(string url, string title, string initCode, string og_desc, string desc, string og_img)
    {
        string Html = "<html lang=\"en\">" +
        "<head>" +
            "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>" +
            "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0\" />" +
            "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"\"/>" +
            "<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"/*OG_DESCRIPTION*/\"/>" +
            "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"'/*OG_IMAGE*/'\"/>" +
            "<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"website\"/>" +
            "<meta property=\"og:site_name\" content=\"\"/>" +
            "<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"OG_URL\"/>" +
            "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"/*DESCRIPTION_DESC*/\"/>" +
            "<meta name=\"twitter:site\" content=\"\"/>" +
            "<title>PAGE_TITLE</title>" +
            "<script>/*PAGE_INIT*/</script>" +
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/.../style.css\" media=\"all\" id=\"styleLink\" />" +
            "<script src=\"...properties/scripts.js\"></script>" +
            "<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"...properties/images/\">" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
            "<div id=\"main\" class=\\">" +
            "</div><!-- /#main -->" +
        "</body>" +
       "</html>";

        Html = Html.Replace("OG_URL", url).Replace("PAGE_TITLE", title).Replace("/*PAGE_INIT*/", initCode).Replace("/*OG_DESCRIPTION*/", og_desc)
            .Replace("/*DESCRIPTION_DESC*/", desc).Replace("/*OG_IMAGE*/", og_img);

        return Html;
    }
</script>
```

The problem was with this parts:

```
"<script>PAGE_INIT</script>" +
"<script src=\"...properties/scripts.js\"></script>"
```

Compiler recognize it as new runat script.
Solution is to divide string which contains script tags:

```
"<script>PAGE_INIT<" + "/script>" +
"<script src=\"...properties/scripts.js\"><" + "/script>"
```

Comment: First though ... is properties.txt in the right location? also does the file have the appropriate permissions set (so that the app can access it)?

Comment: Hi Jimmy. The server is hiding the error. This is because something went wrong and you don't want anyone to see internal details of your code. If you cannot go to the machine itself, you can change the web.config file so it shows you the details. See this article for details: https://stackify.com/web-config-customerrors-asp-net/

Comment: You should not be doing this kind of processing on the render side. But without you enabling the errors there's no way to easily pinpoint the problem area. I would guess that since you are reading a file, the code is not finding the file or you are going out of index in one of the lines.

Comment: @TonyAbrams double checked it, yes it has appropriate permissions. I checked it with a simple method.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file you can turn off the custom errors option by using the following in your system.web:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This will allow the OP to get error information, but it's not really the answer to whatever problem he is facing. This should be a comment.

Comment: Hi, i don't have access to the server right now to change configuration of the file.

Comment: Can you change the web.config locally and redeploy?

Comment: That's quite the unfortunate scenario @JimmyOcha

Comment: Maybe try adding a try catch and then changing something on the page to display the error so that it is less ambiguous. @JimmyOcha